# Custom Facebook posts with API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Not really sure how to explain this. But I am looking to display Facebook posts from a user on a website without any of the Facebook branding or *page plugins*. The title, date, image etc. must be customisable. I am not sure what API which is needed. I was wondering if someone could direct me to where I could look about this subject matter.

If this question has been mentioned before please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed (resp. /user/posts, if you only want the user’s own posts.) You will have to make the user login to your app and grant it permission to access their posts first. If that topic is new to you as well, then start with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: Ahh thank you. That has given me a good sense of direction of where to look. I am trying to get a the feed of a Facebook page (not a user). Looking at this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/page/feed s what I believe is need. I understand Facebook recently had an update. I was wondering if there are any examples of using this approach out there as this version is fairly new.

Comment: Nothing relevant to reading a page’s feed has changed much lately. You will need an access token to make API requests, so you should do this on the server side - there you can use your app access token or a page access token, both of which should not be exposed in client-side code. So if you want to do it client-side, you’d still have to make the visitor log into your app first, so that you could use their user access token. Plus, doing this server-side makes it easier for you to implement some caching; without you would likely run into the Rate Limits rather quickly.